# Adding a class to element whenever an element is added to DOM

Tags: jquery, css, timeout

I have following code in `document.ready()` as :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('img').addClass('myClass');

});
```

Now this code works fine if I **loads all the images** at once, then this function **adds** the **myClass** to them(all img's). 
But what happens here is that whenever a new element with tag **img** like `<img...../>` is added in the DOM (via ajax or javascript), class to it does not gets added.. is it a limitation of JQuery or it provides this via some plugin or api,or we have to do it manually.

I want whenever a new ***img*** is added in DOM its class would set to **myClass**,

***PS*** Right now I used setTimeout() like this to call a function after 2 secs to add classes to my images as :

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('img').addClass('actAsButton');
},2000);
```

But is this the right way of doing, in fact this code also fails if we adds any new  in DOM after 2 secs for that to happen I can use **setInterval** instead but that is quite costly in terms of memory usage.Please shed some light..

Comment: no it's not limitation, it just makes sense not to automatically set anything for any new tag I dynamically add.

Comment: Its not limitation man, why would you automatically aspect to set a tag you dynamically added, it Jquery awesomeness that you have to define when to add! +1 @NiftyDude - hows it bro? B-)

Comment: If you show us how you add new IMG elements to the DOM, we might be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').load(function() {
  $(this).addClass('actAsButton');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `addClass` is not working  because the img element was not there when `$(document).ready()` was fired. S0, you should use following code for that.

```
$('img').live('load', function () {
    $('img').addClass('actAsButton');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('img', 'load', function() {
    $(this).addClass('actAsButton');
});
```